# how function that pass to sort method of array access property of object in that array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function comParison(propertyName){
    return function(obj1,obj2){
       var value1 = obj1[propertyName];
       var value2 = obj2[propertyName];

       if (value1 < value2){
        return -1;
       }else id (value1 > value2){
        return1;
       }else{
        return 0;
       }
    }
  };


var data = [{name:n1},{name:n2}];
data.sort(comParison("name"));
```

this will compare name, but how does comParison function access name property and why it have to pass as string?

Comment: Go checkout associative array in Javascript. That should help.

Comment: @tea_totaler What is an _"associative array"_ in _JavaScript_? Do you mean an _Object_ or an _Array_ of _Objects_?

Comment: *" how does comParison function access name property"* like so: `obj1[propertyName]`. That's called *bracket notation*. *"why it have to pass as string"* because it would not work otherwise.

Comment: Because it's [bracket notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above example is based on closures. Step by step it's roughly like this:

1. `comParison` function accepts `propertyName` as an argument
2. Anonymous function created inside `comParison`, that function has access to `propertyName` and everything else inside `comParison` (and global variables).
3. This anonymous function is then returned as a sorting function
4. By the time this anonymous function is called it *still* has access to `propertyName` variable due to closure, and is, therefore, able to access `obj[propertyName]`

Hope this makes it a bit clear.

[Another useful answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/2454376)